# Creating a Snowflake View with a Sequence

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence

Is it possible to use a Sequence inside a View?? I am using the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW < VIEW_NAME > (ID, VALUE1, VALUE2,...) AS 
    SELECT 
      SEQ1.NEXTVAL, 
      VAL1, 
      VAL2, 
      ...
    FROM 
   < TABLE >
```

But it is giving me the following error:

```
invalid identifier 'SEQ1.NEXTVAL'
```

The query works when not creating the view:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the full qualified name for the SEQ object, because if I am in a different DB/Schema, that is the scope used to look for `SEQ`

basically everything in a view should be fully qualified, tables, views, functions, sequences.

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
create SCHEMA test.test;
use SCHEMA test.test;
create SEQUENCE seq1;

create view test_v as SELECT seq1.nextval;

select * from test.test.test_v;
```

gives:

| NEXTVAL |
| --- |
| 2 |

```
create SCHEMA test.not_test;
use SCHEMA test.not_test;

select * from test.test.test_v;
```

and now you get:

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 29 invalid identifier 'SEQ1.NEXTVAL'

Answer (score 2):

Here SEQ1 is not defined, that is the reason why you see the error. Documentation for Sequences is here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence.html

Comment: I have created the sequence. When I use the select query without creating the view it fetches

Comment: Can you post the output for the sequence query?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output of the query there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Sequence existing? Looks like you accidentally missed to create it.

Comment: No the sequence exists. I can select the vale but cannot create the view.